# Teradata studio express - width_bucket error

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL in Teradata studio express, I am trying to run the following script but getting an error.

```
select customer, total_spend, width_bucket(total_spend, -100, 200, 10)
from data.spend;
```

It says that width_bucket function is not supported? All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please check if [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_width_bucket.htm) helps.

Comment: Please add the **exact** error message you get.